# google chrome asking to change search country

Tags: google-chrome

I use a VPN to connect to the internet with and am using google chrome browser.

Annoyingly, I get a pop-up message regularly asking me if I want to continue using google.se instead of searching with google.de, for example. Pressing no only satisifies it for a short time before asking again and there are no options to turn this off.

Answer (score 0):

I cut and pasted but worked for me:

Or you can just add "/ncr" to the URL of the google site you want and it'll keep you there - [eg](http://www.google.co.uk/ncr)

NCR stands for No Country Redirect.